# Redmine won't start on Ruby Server - undefined method `find_by_name'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

I'm trying to get Redmine 2.4.7 running on Ruby 1.9.3-p551. I have followed the instructions here: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/redmineinstall using

```
bundle install --without development test rmagick
```

My server starts correctly, using this command:

```
C:\Redmine\redmine-2.4.7>ruby script/rails server webrick -e production
 => Booting WEBrick
 => Rails 3.2.19 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:3000
 => Call with -d to detach
 => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
 [2015-01-06 03:44:56] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
 [2015-01-06 03:44:56] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2014-11-13) [i386-mingw32]
 [2015-01-06 03:44:56] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=11844 port=3000
```

But trying to access any page causes this error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `find_by_name' for Setting():Class):
  app/models/setting.rb:243:in `find_or_default'
  app/models/setting.rb:108:in `[]'
  app/models/setting.rb:141:in `rest_api_enabled?'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:119:in `find_current_user'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:100:in `user_setup'
```

I've tried

```
gem update --system
```

But still the same issue.

The gems installed are as follows:

```
C:\Redmine\redmine-2.4.7>gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (3.2.19)
actionpack (3.2.19)
activemodel (3.2.19)
activerecord (3.2.19)
activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (3.2.12)
activeresource (3.2.19)
activesupport (3.2.19)
arel (3.0.3)
bigdecimal (1.1.0)
builder (3.0.0)
bundler (1.7.11)
coderay (1.1.0)
erubis (2.7.0)
hike (1.2.3)
i18n (0.7.0)
io-console (0.3)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (2.0.3)
json (1.8.1, 1.5.5)
mail (2.5.4)
mime-types (1.25.1)
minitest (2.5.1)
multi_json (1.10.1)
net-ldap (0.3.1)
polyglot (0.3.5)
rack (1.4.5)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-openid (1.4.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.4)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (3.2.19)
railties (3.2.19)
rake (10.1.1, 0.9.2.2)
rdoc (3.12.2, 3.9.5)
ruby-openid (2.3.0)
rubygems-update (2.4.5)
sprockets (2.2.3)
thor (0.19.1)
tilt (1.4.1)
tiny_tds (0.5.1 x86-mingw32)
treetop (1.4.15)
tzinfo (0.3.42)
```

The method throwing the error looks like this

```
private
  # Returns the Setting instance for the setting named name
  # (record found in database or new record with default value)
  def self.find_or_default(name)
    name = name.to_s
    raise "There's no setting named #{name}" unless @@available_settings.has_key?(name)
    setting = find_by_name(name)
    unless setting
      setting = new(:name => name)
      setting.value = @@available_settings[name]['default']
    end
    setting
  end
end
```

Comment: Do you have any plugin installed?

Comment: Not at the moment...

Comment: Can you confirm all migrations has been run on the production database without any issue?

Answer (score 1):

`find_by_*` is removed with rails4, But as per the gem list I can see you are using `rails < 4`, But I still believe its something to do with the rails version.

However if you look at the master branch , then have updated the syntax

https://github.com/redmine/redmine/blob/master/app/models/setting.rb#L246

So I believe upgrading your `redmine` should fix the issue

Comment: Thank you. I upgraded Redmine, but now the server won't start; it wont connect to my sql server DB (Redmine 2.4.7 connects fine, with the same config). The Redmine set-up is hard work...

Comment: find_by_name wasn't removed (find_all_by_* and find_by_foo_and_bar were)

Comment: What is your new Redmine version?

Comment: Sorry, should have made that clear! The new Redmine version is 2.6. The error is "cannot connect to Adaptive Server". I copied the database.yml from the Redmine 2.4.7 dir, where the connection is fine. I will post a full stack trace from my PC when I am back in the office tomorrow. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

your output says: 
  app/models/setting.rb:243:in `find_or_default'

Can you show us the method or at least the smallest logical block around line 243?

Comment: Sure - I have added to the question text. Thank you.